# Git takes username from global settings instead of local one

Tags: git, commit

I have changed username and email in local repository that differes from global settings. Now my local `/.git/config` has new lines:

```
[core]

...
[user]
name=user2
email=email2@aaa.com
```

I do project checkout, edit some file, add, commit, push. I was expecting that new change will be registered by `user2`. But instead of that I see that my default global username was used to commit change. Why? How to make git use different name than global one?

Comment: Have you edited manually the file or executed the command `git config user.name user2 ` ? Indentation might be important...

Comment: I have executed command

Comment: Documentation says that even identity can be overidden locally so it's weird... https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

Comment: What's the output of `git config user.name` when you're inside the repo?

Comment: It happened to me, turns out if you are using commit --amend you also must give --reset-author

Answer (score -1):

In the repository where you want to use your second user name type:

> cd your_repository_dir
>
> git config user.name user2